# Converting different length sentences in .txt to .csv file with 2 columns in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a .txt file which contains sentences of variable lengths with their respective ID's attached in the beginning.
Like this:

```
MR1 firstWord secondWord thirdword fourthWord
MR2 some sentence written again.
MR3 some other sentence with variable length of words.
```

I wanted to convert this into a .csv file like this in two columns:

```
MR1 firstWord
MR1 secondWord
MR1 thirdWord
MR1 fourthWord
MR2 some
MR2 sentence
.....
....
....
```

My logic was to apply a double for loop to achieve this, but with my logic the output file is coming out like this:

```
MR1 firstWord secondWord thirdword fourthWord
MR1 some sentence written again.
MR1 some other sentence with variable length of words.
MR2 firstWord secondWord thirdword fourthWord
MR2 some sentence written again.
MR2 some other sentence with variable length of words.
MR3 ....
```

in which each ID is associated with ALL the sentences in the file, which is obviously crooked.

Any help to achieve the desired outcome mentioned above will be greatly appriciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Looks like you've got your loops wrong, you need to split each sentence and then store the variable (MR1 etc.) they map to, in a list or whatever, and then iterate through this list and print MR1 plus each word. Repeat this for each line.

Can't really help show how yours is wrong until you post code though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like,

1. Split each line and store the result into a variable.
2. Iterate over all the elements from the list starting from position 1.
3. Print the 0th element plus the element from the sliced list for each iteration.

Example:

```
>>> s = 'MR1 firstWord secondWord thirdword fourthWord'
>>> for i in s.split()[1:]:
        print(s.split()[0], i)


MR1 firstWord
MR1 secondWord
MR1 thirdword
MR1 fourthWord
```

Exact code would be,

```
with open("file", "r") as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        m = line.split()
        for i in m[1:]:
            print(m[0], i)
```